# how to read linux kernel, any good tools to read kernel?

Tags: version-control, open-source, linux-kernel, google-code, lxr

linux kernel is really worth to spend a lot of time of read, but it is so large, and you don't know how to trace where you should start to read, and what you have read before?

usuallly people try to read linux kernel would make some comments when reading code, anybody agree? so git maybe nice when read linux kernl, but maybe sometimes you would like to read code on web tools such as lxr, but what make you disppointed is that you cannot make comments on lxr.

google code support comment, but you cannot export such comment:(
so what tool you would like to choose if you want to read source code of linux kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot understand the whole kernel at once, not even with a magic tool.  There are too many facets and each has many aspects and quite a few nuances.

I suggest starting with a particular area of interest and focus primarily on it.  If you have never looked at an OS before, the innermost areas are:

- memory management
- process management
- thread scheduling
- file system
- initialization

As far as tools, any good cross referencing website is fine.  [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees) is good, but it takes awhile to get familiar with it.

Comment: why people spend time to read kernel, why not read small project such as httpd or squid?

Answer (score 2):

Before starting with code , some theory knowledge is important.
Professional linux kernel architecture book will be of great help.

Lxr is good for browsing code online 
VI editor with ctags and Taglist plugin is optimal for browsing kernel source code offline.

Comment: but you cannot do comment on lxr...